# Same binding in two separate IIS sites

Tags: iis

I have a site created in IIS7.5 that renders my main website.  I'd like to create a second site that points to a separate document root that contains a very simplified version of the main website for times when traffic is too big.  The idea is that I would shut down the main site and start up the second site.  Obviously both sites contain the same host binding so that they both respond to the same website url.  When I switch between the two sites I keep getting 500 or 503 Service not available errors.  Is this configuration possible in IIS7 or is there a better approach to this?

thanks for you time.

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you would want to handle scenarios when there is a lot of traffic.

The simple answer to this is load balancing. You should either try to scale up [invest in better hardware, add more RAM, CPU etc. if required] OR scale out [add more servers and let them handle the load].